# Как создать объект document в typescript (или js) без использования браузера?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, юнит-тесты

Я пишу тесты для своего проекта на typescript. Использую framework "Testyts". Конструктор одного из моих классов принимает на вход экземпляр интерфейса HTMLElement и производит с ним всевозможные манипуляции. Это будет работать в браузере, потому что я могу написать:

```
document.createElement('div');
```

и передавать его. Однако объект `document` существует только в браузере. А мне нужно написать тесты; они, кажется, браузер использовать не могут.

Вопрос: как я могу эмулировать объект `document`, или создать экземпляр HTMLElement, или распарсить разметку, чтобы typescript ее подцепил?

Comment: использовать ChromeHeadless https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/421137/

Answer (score 0):

Нашел библиотеку, которая эмулирует поведение DOM без самого браузерного движка: [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). Чтобы совместить ее с typescript нужно использовать вторую библиотеку с типами: [@types/jsdom](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jsdom).

После установки, в файл с тестом можно написать код, который представлен ниже: импортируем сам `JSDOM`, потом создаем функцию, которая возвратит пустой объект типа `Document`, и работаем с ним, как с обычным объектом `document` из браузера.

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const getEmptyDocument = (): Document => {
    const dom = new JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>");
    return dom.window.document;
}
```

**Ссылки на npm:**

- [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)
- [@types/jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jsdom)